# MySQL SUM Amount per month and group by caterory

Tags: mysql

I have table:
User nvarchar(30)
Date datetime
Total decimal(8,2)

And i need to get data per month like this:
[image]

I can get it this way (without month columns):

```
SELECT User, MONTHNAME(FROM_UNIXTIME(Date)) as month, SUM(Total) as total FROM `wp_banking_expenses` group by month,User
```

But i need it to make as on image above...

Comment: i noticed in the manual `MONTHNAME()` can only work on **date** datatypes so the `FROM_UNIXTIME()` which returns a **INT** datatype should be invalid and return `NULL` in your query.. see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/k3fSS8EyRXfic1rfDMpqSV/0)

Comment: Check if the existing anwers work for you.. Otherwise i suggest you to read [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) for providing example data and expected results for more accurate answers.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code.

Answer (score 1):

use `conditional aggregation` using `case when expression`

```
select user,max(case when month='January' then total end) as Jan,
max(case when month='February' then total end) as Feb,
max(case when month='March' then total end) as Mar,
max(case when month='April' then total end) as Apr,
max(case when month='May' then total end) as May,
max(case when month='June' then total end) as June,
----
from
(
SELECT User, MONTHNAME(Date) as month, SUM(Total) as total
FROM `wp_banking_expenses` 
group by month,User
)A group by user
```

Comment: needs a little bit more tweaking.. [MONTHNAME()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_monthname) returns the full month names like `January, February`, so the cases will not match

Comment: Also just noticed `MONTHNAME()` can only work on **date** datatypes so the `FROM_UNIXTIME()` which returns a **INT** datatype should be invalid and return `NULL` in your query.. see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/k3fSS8EyRXfic1rfDMpqSV/0)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use condition aggregate function.

```
SELECT  User, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN MONTHNAME(Date) =  'January' THEN Total END) as Jan, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN MONTHNAME(Date) =  'February' THEN Total END) as Feb,
        SUM(CASE WHEN MONTHNAME(Date) =  'March' THEN Total END) as Mar,
        SUM(CASE WHEN MONTHNAME(Date) =  'April' THEN Total END) as Apr,
        SUM(CASE WHEN MONTHNAME(Date) =  'May' THEN Total END) as May,
        SUM(CASE WHEN MONTHNAME(Date) =  'June' THEN Total END) as JUN,
        SUM(CASE WHEN MONTHNAME(Date) =  'July' THEN Total END) as JUL, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN MONTHNAME(Date) =  'August' THEN Total END) as AUG,
        SUM(CASE WHEN MONTHNAME(Date) =  'September' THEN Total END) as SEP,
        SUM(CASE WHEN MONTHNAME(Date) =  'October' THEN Total END) as OCT,
        SUM(CASE WHEN MONTHNAME(Date) =  'November' THEN Total END) as NOV,
        SUM(CASE WHEN MONTHNAME(Date) =  'December' THEN Total END) as DEC
FROM `wp_banking_expenses` 
group by User
```

Comment: needs a little bit more tweaking.. [MONTHNAME()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_monthname) returns the full month names like `January, February`, so the cases will not match

Comment: @RaymondNijland Thanks

Comment: Also just noticed `MONTHNAME()` can only work on **date** datatypes so the `FROM_UNIXTIME()` which returns a **INT** datatype should be invalid and return `NULL` in your query.. see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/k3fSS8EyRXfic1rfDMpqSV/0)